# No syntax highlight on Windows VisualStudio 2015 with Solidity extension

Tags: solidity, visual-studio

I'm trying to set up my smart contract environment with:
* VS Enterprise 2015
* Solidity extension

Everything installs fine but I don't get syntax highlight and I can't deploy contracts (Deployment to http://localhost:8000/ started! User used for deployment: testuser User check failed!)

I've also installed bloc

Any ideas?

Comment: In VS Community 2015 also